# MySQLi Prepared Statement Query Results in an Array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, prepared-statement

Trying to transition over my old mysql queries to mysqli prepared statements. I've got everything figured out except for one thing. How can I get the query results stored as an array? I used to do this like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) {
 // do stuff
}
```

Now I have the following code. In this case, my array is a single record, so I don't need to iterate over it, but I want to hold it as an array so that I can refer to its field names. Also, I will have other queries that will return multiple records, so I'll need to iterat then.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users 
    WHERE (LOWER(first_name)=LOWER(?) && LOWER(last_name)=LOWER(?))";
$stmt =  mysqli_stmt_init($link);
$this_user;

if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {

    /* Bind the input parameters to the query */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $first_name, $last_name);

    /* execute query, store results in an array */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        mysqli_close($link);
        $tag_result = "failure";
        $tag_message = "No matching user found";
        echo encodeJSONObj($tag_result, $tag_message);
        die();
    }

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 1) {
        mysqli_close($link);
        $tag_result = "failure";
        $tag_message = "Multiple records found for this user.";
        echo encodeJSONObj($tag_result, $tag_message);
        die();
    }

    $this_user = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

$id                     = $this_user['id'];
$first_name             = $this_user['first_name'];
$last_name              = $this_user['last_name'];
// and so on...
```

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

EDIT: With big thanks to Phil, I've modified my code. However, I still seem to be returning 0 rows even though my input parameters should return exactly 1 row. Here is what I have:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, first_name, last_name, group_id, email, cell
            FROM Users 
            WHERE (first_name=? && last_name=?)";
$stmt =  mysqli_stmt_init($link);

if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {

    /* Bind the input parameters to the query */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $first_name, $last_name);

    /* execute query, bind result, and fetch value */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $first_name, $last_name,  $group_id, $email, $cell);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

    if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 0) {
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        mysqli_close($link);
        echo "No results returned";
        die();
    }

    ...
}
```

This always outputs `No results returned` when it should find 1 row and skip right past that block. I've been staring at this for a long time, but I just can't see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why did I get a -1 for this? Sheez!

Comment: Obviously because this question doesn't show any research effort, as it is written in the vote button tooltip

Comment: You need to `execute()` the prepared statement before attempting to fetch anything or count the number of rows. I suggest you read this - http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php#example-1636

Comment: Thanks, @Phil. That was included in one my many attempts, but I got the same result. I didn't include it here, but I will edit my post to show what I did.

Comment: This should be throwing errors as you're passing a `mysqli_stmt` into `mysqli_fetch_array` which expects a `mysqli_result`. I'd say you've got `error_reporting` too low and / or `display_errors` disabled. You're also *attempting* to pass an array into `mysqli_num_rows` which won't work either

Answer (score 5):

Your script contains numerous errors (as mentioned in comments above). Here's a simple step-by-step...

1. Prepare a statement and bind parameters

   ```
   $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
   if (!$stmt) {
       throw new Exception($link->error, $link->errno);
   }

   // you can error check this too but it rarely goes wrong
   $stmt->bind_param('ss', $first_name, $last_name);
   ```
2. Execute the statement and store the result

   ```
   if (!$stmt->execute()) {
       throw new Exception($stmt->error, $stmt->errno);
   }
   $stmt->store_result();
   ```
3. Do your *number of row* checks against `$stmt->num_rows`...

   ```
   if ($stmt->num_rows == 0) {
       // ... 
   }
   if ($stmt->num_rows > 1) {
       // ...
   }
   ```
4. Bind and fetch the result

   ```
   // This relies on the SELECT column ordering.
   // You should probably change your SELECT statement to
   // SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM Users...
   $stmt->bind_result($id, $first_name, $last_name);
   $stmt->fetch();
   $stmt->close();
   $link->close();
   ```

   If you want to fetch the single result row as an associative array, try this instead

   ```
   $result = $stmt->get_result(); // note - this requires the mysqlnd driver
   $this_user = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   $result->free();
   $stmt->close();
   $link->close();
   ```

Comment: Thanks again, @Phil. I know that I can do this by binding the result to every field individually. What I was looking for was something more akin to the old mysql method where the results are stored in an array object. My records contain almost 20 fields, so I was trying to avoid my code getting messy with lots of parameters in the bind result command. This also has significant implications with other lines of code later in the function. Looks like that's what I need to do, though. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @usr55410 I've updated my answer with an associative array fetch example for the last step